# Is this not how memory allocation works in R

Tags: r

I was testing how the RAM/memory allocation works in R.
For example, the object size of Iris (150 rows) is 8.9 kb (I am assuming for 1 row it is 8.9/150).
But for 1 row, the object size is 2.06 kb (How is it?) . Can anyone explain?

So is this  not how allocation works.
Total Memory = No of rows * memory / per each row

```
> object_size(iris)
8.9 kB
> object_size(head(iris,n = 1))
2.06 kB
> 2.06 * 150
[1] 309 kb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite, the dataframe itself takes quite a bit of memory, just the structure. Try this

```
> object.size(head(iris,n = 1))
1896 bytes
> object.size(head(iris,n = 2))
1928 bytes
> object.size(head(iris,n = 3))
2000 bytes
```

for a feeling.

Comment: I see. But what is the difference between object.size and object_size?

Comment: @manup I don't know, object.size is from base R.

Comment: so you mean the difference is not related to number of rows? right?

Comment: @manup The point is that you cannot just divide by the number of rows like that. A better approximation is to remove the size which is taken by the dataframe, and then check how much each additional row adds to the memory, that gives you a better estimate of memory for each row.

Comment: But when I tried ````object.size(head(iris,n = 1))```` , i am getting 2120 bytes. I know my understanding is wrong , can you please explain? Is it because, other objects is consuming some ram?

Comment: Vectors take memory to describe what is in them.  A dataframe is a vector containing vectors.  So you get overhead for the dataframe plus overhead for each column before you start counting the data.